# Relationship between U-boot CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE and SDRAM

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, ram, bootloader, u-boot

At present, my understanding of u-boot is as follows

1. ROM Code load SPL
2. SPL initialize RAM, and load u-boot to **CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE** RAM address
3. u-boot relocates itself
4. Boot the kernel

I check my u-boot configuration, **CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE** is `0x80000000`, but I am curious, my RAM size is only 1G, and it still can work fine.

1G is equal to `0x40000000`, less than `0x80000000`

So, I want to know if I have a misunderstanding about **CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE** or my concept is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> I check my u-boot configuration, CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE is 0x80000000, but I am curious, my RAM size is only 1G, and it still can work fine.
>
> 1G is equal to 0x40000000, less than 0x80000000
>
> So, I want to know if I have a misunderstanding about CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE or my concept is wrong?

Your understanding of `CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE` is correct.  What is wrong is that the RAM size is related to the RAM physical start address.  The RAM starts at 0x80000000 and ends at 0xC0000000 (1G later).  So 0xC0000000-0x80000000 = 0x40000000 = 1G.

You would have an issue if your ram was at 0xD0000000 an was 1G big or something like that.  Normally people would not build such a system.

Comment: The manual for the chip in question likely has a memory map section which will say where in the address space various things reside, such as that DRAM starts at 0x80000000 and can be as large as ....something.

Comment: How can I know what the start address of ram? Why not start with 0?
When u-boot is loaded into the ram, the address space u-boot saw was from 0x00000000 to 0x40000000 or 0x80000000 to 0xC0000000?

Comment: U-boot will see 0x80000000-0xc0000000.  This is fine.  An OS like linux uses an MMU so physical addresses don't matter.  U-boot probably switches on the MMU so that the caches can be used.  However, there is no technical reason to map RAM at 0x0.  In fact, it is often useful if a NULL pointer access causes an exception at least while developing.