# Debugging u-boot

Tags: debugging, u-boot, entry-point

I am using NXP-S32G evaluation board and try to debug u-boot before and after relocation. I build uboot with configs/s32g274aevb_qspi_defconfig.

1- The entry point in the elf file is CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE = 0x34020000 but the flashing address of u-boot.bin is 0x24400, so how would it be possible to debug before relocation is done? the addresses in the image and in the elf file are not matching ?, is there a specific procedure or configuration that should be done ?

2- I am a bit confused about CONFIG_SYS_TEXT_BASE, [here](https://source.denx.de/u-boot/u-boot/-/blob/HEAD/README#L2388) it says that is the flashing address of uboot but [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55303762/relationship-between-u-boot-config-sys-text-base-and-sdram) it says that is the adress in RAM where uboot gets copied after relocation, so what is the right answer

Comment: The root of your confusion seems to be that you don't know what the boot medium is, that is whether U-Boot ***(a)*** is *executed in place* (i.e. XIP) directly from flash (e.g. NOR flash), or ***(b)*** is copied from (NAND?) flash to RAM and then executed from memory.  Note that the copy operation of (b) is referred to as *loading* and not *"relocation"*.   Are these XY questions, and that your real problem is that you're trying to boot using the **elf** file instead of using the **u-boot.bin** file?

Comment: I am booting from the NOR flash and I am flashing the u-boot.bin file, the elf file is used for debugging it is only loaded to the debugger and not flashed in the target, for sure the u-boot will start executing from NOR (XIP) but at a certain point it will relocate itself to RAM, this is my undrestanding